# How to install eclipse neon version for 32 bit system in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, ubuntu-14.04, eclipse-neon

I downloaded eclipse neon version from here
[elipse-neon for 32 bit](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/oomph/epp/neon/R/eclipse-inst-linux64.tar.gz)

When i tried to run eclipse,error i am getting is:

```
ujjwal@ujjwal:~/Downloads/eclipse$ ./eclipse -vm /usr/bin
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library   /home/ujjwal/Downloads/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.401.v20161122-1740/eclipse_1618.so which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The  org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the state location was initialized.  Will retry after the state location is initialized.
```

**My system is 32 bit**. And java version is:

```
ujjwal@ujjwal:~/Downloads/eclipse$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
```

- Problem 1: Why java HotSpot server is 64-bit? Will it work with my system which is a 32 bit system.I think the error is related to this.
- Problem 2: How to launch eclipse neon with java 8 support. What am i missing.?

PS: I have tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/392097/how-do-i-install-32-bit-libraries-when-they-keep-having-uninstallable-dependenci), [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/515529/gtk-message-failed-to-load-module-unity-gtk-module-ubuntu-14-04) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342202/failed-to-load-module-canberra-gtk-module-but-already-installed), but nothing worked for me.

Comment: It would only be 64-bit if that's what you installed. You can't mix and match 32 and 64-bit Eclipse and Java.

Comment: you caught me right! I have tried installing and reinstalling java-8 for 32 bit ubuntu many times. But I am really not getting why every time it is showing as 64 bit. I removed java completely, again i reinstalled but its the same problem. I have tried these tutorials-
[link-1](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-oracle-java-8-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts/)  

[link-2](http://askubuntu.com/questions/759413/unable-to-install-java-8-on-ubuntu-14-04-32-bit)

[link-3](http://askubuntu.com/questions/817151/ubuntu-14-04-install-java-8-not-working)

where am i doing wrong?

Comment: Are you on 64-bit Ubuntu? In theory you shouldn't be able to run a 64-bit binary at all otherwise.

Comment: yeah,I checked just now. you're right I am on 64-bit ubuntu, and my system is 32 bit.

Comment: Given the struggle you've had with the JVM, it might be more expedient to grab the 64-bit Eclipse download. After all, setting up Eclipse isn't your end goal.

Comment: okay, will do that! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Download** eclipse-java-neon-2-linux-gtk.tar.gz [click here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/neon/2/eclipse-java-neon-2-linux-gtk.tar.gz)

than

Press **Ctrl+Alt+T** on keyboard to open the terminal. When it opens, run the command below to extract Eclipse to /opt/:

**cd /opt/ && sudo tar -zxvf ~/Downloads/eclipse-java-neon-2-linux-gtk.tar.gz**

You may replace “eclipse-*.tar.gz” (without quote) to the exact package name if the command does not work.

Don’t like Linux commands? You can do this by opening Nautilus file browser via root: Press **Alt+F2** -> run gksudo nautilus.

Once done, you should see the eclipse folder under /opt/ directory.

Press Ctrl+Alt+T, paste below command into the terminal and hit enter (install gksu from Software Center if below command does not work).

**gksudo gedit /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop**

Above command will create and open the launcher file for eclipse with gedit text editor.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I followed all these steps. 
But last command is throwing an error :

`ujjwal@ujjwal:/opt$ gksudo gedit /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop

(gksudo:19263): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema 'com.canonical.desktop.interface' is not installed

Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)`

Comment: Resolved the error by reinstalling, using this command-
`sudo apt-get install overlay-scrollbar* `
After successfully running this command -
`gksudo gedit /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop`
 , "eclipse.dekstop" named blank file opened in text editor. What next, now?
I am trying to launch eclipse same error as i mentioned in the question is coming.

Comment: But the problem has not been resolved. When i launch eclipse, same error is coming, as i mentioned in the question.

Comment: eclipse 32 bit is not supporting Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit so you need to install jdk 1.8 32 bit

Comment: yeah, i get it. But the thing is, i am stuck here. I have tried to install- reinstall many times **32 bit version of java-8** on my system but i dont know why its showing **Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server** everytime. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 0):

With regard to the answer by Raj: installing Eclipse with root permissions is not recommended, because Eclipse prefers to update configuration files inside the installation. If that's not possible, any configuration updates are written to `${HOME}/.eclipse/` which is sligthly restricted in several regards.

In particular selecting the correct JVM to run Eclipse can be done via editing [eclipse.ini](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini).

**EDIT:** In fact much installation hassle can be avoided by using the [installer](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/oomph/epp/neon/R2a/eclipse-inst-linux32.tar.gz), see the corresponding box on the [download page](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/), which has a nice explanation when you click on **Find out more**.